# Verbs collocating with the term "jet lag" used both as the subject and the object

Tags: word-usage, word-request, collocations

Someone who has made a long journey from east to west by plane feels as if the time were several hours later than the local time.

Looking for the term which may be applied to that phenomenon (or a physiological condition as it's called in the article I'm providing a link to), I came upon "[jet lag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_lag)", and now I'm trying to use it to describe someone who starts yawning at daytime because of the feeling of tiredness  due to jet lag. after travelling though different time zones by plane, say, from New York City to London.

What I need is the verb(s) collocating with jet lag used both as the subject and the object.

The suggestions I could so far come up with are the following:

> His jet lag first manifested in a deep yawn.
>
> His deep yawn showed that his jet lag was seriously affecting him.
>
> His jet lag caught up with him, and he began to yawn.
>
> By six P.M., he began to suffer from jet lag, and now he was struggling to
>   stifle his yawns.

Would any of my suggestions work? If not, could someone possibly suggest a few alternatives?

Comment: They all work for me.

Comment: There is also the adjective form: [**jet-lagged**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jet-lagged).  "He was so **jet-lagged** that he had to struggle to stifle his yawns."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These suggestions are all reasonable. "Jet-lag" is rather like a disease, and the sort of language that you could use with an illness (like "the 'flu") also works for jet-lag.

> He has jet-lag
>   He is suffering from jet-lag
>   He started to experience the symptoms of jet-lag...

There is a useful adjective form "He is jet-lagged"